# How to add a reload button in nav bar without violating session?

Tags: php, html, reload

So I am trying to reload through a nav bar element in the code below:

```
<div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class ="container">
                <a href="settings.php" class = "navbar-brand" >
                <img class = "navbar-brand"   style="padding: 0.5em;width: 3.8em; height: 3.8em; float: left; margin-top: -1.25em" src="menuconreal.png">
                </a>
                <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href = "login.php">RELOAD</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "index.php">LOG OUT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But on pressing reload, I get the error "You do not have permission to view this page" which is probably due to session violation. So how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you call for `session_start();` at the top of `login.php`?

Comment: Just below the <head></head>. I think I get what you mean, do you want me to place the session start after this RELOAD declaration?

Comment: Right.. stop being lazy and actually LEARN some PHP before you start messing around with complicated stuff that's way behound your level of comprehension. You can't dive in the deep without getting your swimming certificate first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class ="container">
            <a href="settings.php" class = "navbar-brand" >
            <img class = "navbar-brand"   style="padding: 0.5em;width: 3.8em; height: 3.8em; float: left; margin-top: -1.25em" src="menuconreal.png">
            </a>
            <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a onclick="window.location.reload();">RELOAD</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "index.php">LOG OUT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```